# Convergence radius of the Mac-Laurin-series of $f(x)=\frac{x+\sin(x^2)}{e^{x^2}+x^4}\cdot 2x$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

> What is the convergence radius of the Mac-Laurin-series of
>
> $$f(x)=\frac{x+\sin(x^2)}{e^{x^2}+x^4}\cdot 2x$$ ?

Motivation : I would like to study the number $$\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{t}+\sin(t)}{e^t+t^2}dt$$ , which can be transformed to $$\int_0^1 \frac{x+\sin{x^2}}{e^{x^2}+x^4}\cdot 2x\ dx$$ by the substitution $t=x^2$.

I would like to calculate the value of the integral with high precision ($10^5$ digits or more) , so I wonder whether the Mac-Laurin-series of the integrand converges in $[0,1]$. If not, does someone know another method ?

The PARI/GP-algorithm fails already, if $15000$ digits are required (at least if the stack memory is limited to $256MB$).

Answer (score 1):

The radius of convergence is the least absolute value of a root (in the complex plane) of the denominator $e^{x^2} + x^4$.  Those roots are 
$ \pm \sqrt{2 W(\pm i/2)}$, where $W$ is the Lambert W function.  The numerical value is approximately $.9219172370$.  Since this is less than $1$, the series does **not** converge on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you. So, the Mac-Laurin-series is not sufficient.